Weird behaviour trying to plot circumference in 3D
I'm trying to draw a circumference of radius 1 on the xy plane, centered in the origin, and I'm encountering a strange behaviour which I can't seem to figure out the reason for.
My code is
\begin{figure}[b]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=center,
    axis on top=false,
    xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, zlabel={$z$},
    xmin=-1.5, xmax=1.5,
    ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5, 
    zmin=0.0, zmax=2,
    samples=20,
    z buffer=sort,
    tick label style={draw=none}, 
    ticks=none,
]
    \addplot3[thick, -stealth, BrickRed] coordinates {(0,0,0)(0,0,1)};
    \node at (0.125,0.125,1.1) [BrickRed] {$\vec{B}_0$};
    \addplot3[thick, -stealth, BrickRed] coordinates {(0,0,0)(cos(300),sin(300),0)};
    \node at (0.9,-1.1,0) [BrickRed] {$\vec{B}_1(t)$};
    \addplot3[dotted, domain=0:360, smooth] ({cos(x)},{sin(x)},{0});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}

which outputs the following:

Any ideas on why this is the produced output and/or how to correct it?

please complete your code so it can be compiled. as-is, it will only produce errors.

Welcome. // Please don't let your code be unattended by a documentclass (and whatever it takes to compile it) ;-) Thank you

In the key-value pairs of the axis environment, by commenting out line one by one, I noticed that the z buffer=sort line appears to be the root of this problem. I admit I don't truly understand how the z-buffering algorithm in PGFPlots really works, only that removing this line fixed the issue.
As an aside, you can link nodes directly to the end of your plots in PGFPlots, so that you don't need to manually input node coordinates for your variable labels for each vector. This way, if you decide to choose a different angle for your diagram, you won't need to manually input new coordinates for the node with the variable name; it'll just be some small tweaking of the position of the node's text.

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines  = center,
    axis on top = false,
    ticks       = none,
    xlabel      = {$x$},
    ylabel      = {$y$},
    zlabel      = {$z$},
    xmin = -1.5, xmax = 1.5,
    ymin = -1.5, ymax = 1.5, 
    zmin =  0.0, zmax = 2,
    samples     = 20,
    clip mode   = individual
%    z buffer=sort
]
    % Red vector arrow B_0, and place variable name above right of end of vector
    \addplot3[thick, -stealth, red]
       coordinates {(0,0,0)(0,0,1)}
       node [red, above right = -2pt] {$\vec{B}_0$};
       
    % Red vector arrow B_1
    \addplot3[thick, -stealth, red]
        coordinates {(0,0,0) (cos(300),sin(300),0)}
        node (B1_vector_end) {};
    % escape node being clipped, and place it below end of vector
    \node[red, below = -1pt] at (B1_vector_end)  {$\vec{B}_1(t)$};

    % Dotted circle around the origin
    \addplot3[dotted, domain=0:360, samples y=0, smooth] (
        {cos(x)},
        {sin(x)},
        0
    );
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


thanks a lot! Super helpful

Hi @Cioc, I'm glad you found this useful! If you could mark my answer as Accepted by clicking the check mark beneath the voting buttons, I'd be very grateful :)
